# Первичный ключ на несколько столбцов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Видел, что люди делают двойной РК, но так и не понял зачем. В чём преимущество перед банальным созданием id, с которым потом намного проще работать.

Насколько распространена такая практика вообще и в чём преимущества?

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под двойным PK. PK по нескольким полям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от задачи и контекста.

Бывает, что `id` числовой излишен. Ну или у вас поиск именно по этим полям.

Можно, конечно, сделать синтетический числовой `id`, а на поля, которые используются при поиске, навесить вторичные индексы, но это не всегда необходимо.

Скажем, в слабых сущностях не делают лишний числовой `id`.

Как пример, есть у вас две таблицы:

**Игра**

```
-------------------
| id_game | name |
-------------------
```

**Жанр**

```
-------------------
| id_genre | name |
-------------------
```

Игра может быть в нескольких жанрах одновременно, каждый жанр у многих игр. Типичная связь `m:n`.

Для связи используется дополнительная таблица, чтоб указать, к каким жанрам относится игра.

**Игра-Жанр**

```
----------------------
| id_game | id_genre |
----------------------
```

Здесь первичный ключ будет по двум полям.

Comment: А в скорости будет какой нибудь выигрыш?

Comment: @PaulWall количество полей в PK не так сильно влияет, насколько я помню. А вот размер и тип влияют. Тут вопрос не в скорости больше, а в требованиях. Если на вашу таблицу ссылаются другие таблицы, то, очевидно, лучше делать 1 столбец (int/uuid), даже если он будет суррогатным.